# Issue on Running Function in jQuery setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please take a look at this demo and let me know why I am getting undefined error on `DoSomething`?

```js
function DoSomething() {
  console.log("This is Map");
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval('DoSomething()', 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I am getting this error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: DoSomething is not defined

Comment: The posted code, and the stack-snippet, works perfectly fine?

Comment: This is working fine, even if i run it in the current page's console.

Comment: its running ok on my chrome console.

Comment: For people who would like to ONLY vote down questions! Please take a look at this [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/udyfz8vb/) !

Comment: adeneo , Rajaprabhu, and Sebastian, Please check the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/udyfz8vb/) ?

Answer (score 0):

This works fine but to preserve the syntax we must remove the single quotes, try this code:

```js
function DoSomething() {
  document.write("This is Map");
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(DoSomething, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```